# How to hide button when image is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a relativelayout within a scrollview with 12 buttons.  On each button clicked an image displays  all works well, however i can see the image in the background but still have all the button on top of the image.  Is there a way of hiding these buttons?  I don't really want to use a sliding drawer but if i have to i will.  Thanks in advance

Okay so this is my class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.campfacilities);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aimage);

 next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1));
            }

        });
```

How would i then implement the

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: all the button are displayed, however when i set it to gone i can't click on it.  I would like to click on it and all buttons to dissapear and then get them back when i want to select something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the buttons visibility gone like this

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and to show that button again

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Thanks

Comment: I have update my question, could you please let me know how to implement this code?

Answer (score 1):

Consider including all 12 buttons in Single Layout.And Set its visibility to GONE.
So that you will not have to Hide each button individually.

Answer (score 0):

`button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Repeat this for each of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `ImageView` is in the same layout as the ScrollView/Buttons? Well, then simply put the ImageView after the ScrollView in your XML-file. Through this it will overlay your Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are going to use the functionality not only one time, i would offer you to use ViewStub. For more information you may visit the following link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

Or you can listen to Google i/0 lecture about UI by Romain Guy.